# Print output too long to be displayed in Anaconda console

Tags: pandas, dataframe, printing, anaconda, info

I have a pandas dataframe with:

- 2,260,668 records
- 153 columns

I tried to print out the dataframe info in Anaconda Console by using this code:

```
print(df.info())
```

but I get the following output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2260668 entries, 68407277 to 88215728
Columns: 153 entries, member_id to SampleType
dtypes: float64(113), int32(1), int64(1), object(38)
memory usage: 2.6+ GB
None
```

Therefore I cannot view the dataframe info.

Can anyone suggest what I should do to view the full print output please?

Comment: try `df.info(verbose = True)` and also you can try execute your code in jupyter notebook to have a better view

Comment: that worked: thanks!